# How to make asynchronous post requests in java

Tags: java, post

I have a list of 10 maps which having requests to make a post call. I need to iterate these maps and issue a POST request in java using concurrency.

I want each thread to issue two post requests at a time in parallel and I don't want to wait for the response for these. I just need to hit these 10 requests parallel using 5 threads.

My issue is that it is not hitting parallel requests. It is waiting for the response and taking one thread for each request. I would like to take two requests for thread hit the requests concurrently.

My code is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalList.size(); i++) {
        String eachJsonReq = finalList.get(i);
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(api_url,eachJsonReq);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();

public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final String url;
        private final String jsonInputData;

        MyRunnable(String url,String jsonInputData) {
            this.url = url;
            this.jsonInputData = jsonInputData;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                doPost(url,jsonInputData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }

public static void doPost(String url, String data) throws Exception {
    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(data);

    //OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    //writer.write(data);
    System.out.println("Hitted url is "+url+" with data is "+data);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    conn.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: you can use CompleteFuture of Java

Comment: can you please suggest or provide me the sample code to hit post request using completefuture @BERGUIGAMohamedAmine

Comment: You forgot showing `executor`. If you want 5 threads, an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` might be a good pick.